# Android : setNextFocus from MenuItem to button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, accessibility, android-menu

I need to set the NextFocus from MenuItem in the ActionBar to the Button in the layout. 
I tried to get the MenuItem by using Id and setNext Focus of it to the Button in the layout, it doesn't work.

I tried setting the customView in the Menu and using getActionView i got the view, then tried setting the Next focus to the button, it doesn't work.

Am i missing something. Any help appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.